# Why is bluetooth not supported in Android TV SDK?

Tags: android-tv

What is the rationale for bluetooth not being supported on Android TV?  The Nexus TV has a Bluetooth 4.1 radio.  It also connects to accessories via bluetooth.  According to the "Unsupported TV Features" section in the "Handling TV Hardware" documentation bluetooth is listed as not supported.
https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/hardware.html

I'd like to build an app that allows the end user to synchronize their IOT device with an Android TV.  One of the challenges of IOT systems is making the synchronization of data as friction-less as possible.  By using an Android TV device that's in their living room, the user would need to only have their IOT device in their living room for it to synchronize.

Comment: Could you please specify exactly which SDK are you talking about?

Comment: I updated my question with the documentation that says bluetooth is not supported in Android TV.  Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For current (2017) Android TV, Bluetooth is fully supported, as stated by the page you linked above.

Apparently, this page *used* to state Bluetooth is not supported but this was incorrect and was fixed in 2015; ref: https://github.com/aosp-exynos4/android_frameworks_base/commit/c283670669b9510638ef4089eded8597576c1e44

Please note this is not a link to the 'official' change log as the linked website source is not publicly available AFAIK and there's no way to view the changes over time on it.

Comment: Could you please provide links and/or further explanation as to why you claim that the Bluetooth API (Classic ? Low Energy ?) is **fully** supported on Android TV SDK ? Starting from which version ? Thanks.

Comment: @Mackovich Actually it's a good comment and I should have done so. I've modified my answer to include why I came to this statement.

Comment: Okay thanks. Anyway, I bought a Leelbox Q2 with Bluetooth 4.0 and I cannot seem to be able to develop on it either via USB or Wireless ADB. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: anyway, I managed to have an app allowing me WiFi debugging. Strangely enough, the Leelbox is pre-rooted. That was quite surprising! So I tested a discovery scan and it works, but it does not detect LE devices. I also tested pre-Lollipop LE scan and Lollipop+ scan this is what I get: **D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
 D/BluetoothLeScanner: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5**, and then nothing, no results :/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's because they're trying to sell the Google OnHub.

https://on.google.com/hub/